# Visual Studio Web Deploy backup before publish

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I use Visual Studio Web Deploy for an MVC and WCF projects, I'd like that whenever I publish that the deployment directory is backed up in a zip file.

I had a look at the "BeforePublish" target in MSBuild but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about it, nor do I know how to get the output directory.

So Question is, how do I copy the output directory before publish to a zip file named Web-%datetime%.zip .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused what does ClickOnce have anything to do with this question? ClickOnce is for windows apps not web apps. I'm guessing you meant that you are using Web Deploy (AKA MSDeploy). Also can you clarify your question a bit more. Are you trying to backup what is on your server before publish and if so do you want them to be stored locally or on the server?

Comment: Yes I edited the question to say web deploy rather than click once, I want it to back up on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use TFS Team Build to build our web applications and produce a package. The deployment script we use simply does a `sync` to a backup package before doing a `sync` from the built package to the target web site.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have a license for TFS. I use cruise control. What I was hoping was that it was possible within VS.

Comment: It is possible. Use "Build package", then do what my script does.

Answer (score 2):

Web Deploy 3.0 ([currently RC](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2012/04/19/announcing-web-deploy-3-0-release-candidate.aspx)) [supports backing up of various providers](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1281/web-deploy-automatic-backups/).